# Facebook messenger not displaying profile pictures

Tags: facebook-messenger

My Facebook messenger app is not displaying profile pictures of all my friends on Facebook. Under my Facebook app settings, sync all is on.

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you have decent internet speed? Just clear cache once, and reopen application. Sometimes a sync issue occurs

Comment: I dont think my internet speed is the problem caus i've already done this on my wife's tablet and just after the installation voila! There goes all the pix of her friends..